# bash ldap too long output

Tags: bash, ldap, openldap, ldif

In Bash I would like to do an ldap query. It went well but in the output it cuts the end of the line when it's a long line.

For example it's fine, it reaches the domain component:

```
# cn, ou4, ou3, ou2, ou1, dc
```

When there are organization units with many children, it cuts:

```
# cn, ou7, ou6, ou5, ou4, ou3
```

How can I get the whole line every time?

Is it the problem of the linux terminal or something?

Comment: What utility are you using to query the server? Please show your command line invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LDIF, defined in [rfc2849](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2849), may be folded by inserting a line-separator character and a space, except between bytes of a multi-byte UTF-8 character. The utility the client uses to perform a search may have an option to not fold the output lines.